# how to extract specific column in class mids data after multiple imputation by mice in R?

Tags: r, imputation

I have 20% missing values in my dataset for some variables. after using the mice package in R (with m=5), I got 5 MI datasets as class mids data. I want to do further analysis (reduced rank regression which refers rrr form here) by using the MI datasets. how do I extract specific columns from the MI datasets as the response variable and predictors in my rrr model?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rrr package requires two dataframes, one for of the predictor variables and one of the response variables.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rrr/rrr.pdf

You can use dplyr::select to select the column names you want to keep in both. If you are new to R, start with install.packages("dplyr") and library(dplyr).

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this one but this does not work.the select() function seems like can only be used for data frames. after I run the mice code, the class of imp is "mids", it could not be used for select() function.  I thought it might be possible to do rrr with complete() data one by one but how can I pool the results afterthen? I am so confused, looking forward to here you.                                                                 imp <- mice(data,m=5,seed=5,maxit = 5)

Comment: It looks like the mice package has a pool function for you to directly apply regressions. Scroll down a bit on this link: https://datascienceplus.com/imputing-missing-data-with-r-mice-package/

Comment: Yes, I know the pool () function. and it works well on my data if I pool results of cox regression or linear regression, but not for rrr. my problem now is how to do rrr in different multiple imputation datasets and then pool the results out. I think if I can figure out how to extract columns as new response variables for rrr, this problem can be solved. but I don't know how yet.

Comment: What about the complete function? https://nerler.github.io/EP16_Multiple_Imputation/practical/05_Working_with_Imputed_Data_in_Different_Formats.html